# How much effort would it take to build a web store in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

Another slightly non-technical question, but I couldn't decide whether to ask here or on Server Fault...

I can't say I'm an MVC guru yet, but I've built several LOB applications so far in ASP.NET and WPF/Silverlight and am currently working on one in MVC 2, so I do know my way around for the most part. My concern is more about the accounting side of things.

It's easy to go wrong; for instance, I once got hired to fix a situation where reports on old transaction records were being calculated using new taxes. Obviously I know now to avoid that particular problem, but there's all sorts of other things as well, especially when international billing becomes involved.

There are packages like Magento and OSCommerce (the latter of which I've used with pretty good success) for PHP, but that's the thing -- they rely on the LAMP stack. Integrating it with the rest of the website could prove to be a real pain, especially if I end up having to host it on a separate Linux machine -- which I probably will. Juggling user accounts and styling and all that would be a killer.

A lot of the MVC tutorials out there are tutorials in building e-commerce sites -- which is pretty cool, but they're still just tutorials, and I doubt they cover all the issues.

Anyone have any experience in this area?

**Edit:** Commerce Server, at $7,000 per CPU, is out of the question for me, unfortunately.

**Edit 2:** Wait, it looks like Commerce Server's also available on TechNet... not sure if it's a commercial license though.

Comment: I know Magento is supported on the WAMP stack and i atleast did not encounter any major issues. I know this doesnt answer your question about MVC but since u put LAMP as the major concern - have u explored Magento on WAMP?

Comment: @In Sane, It might work. It would probably depend on my webhosting, which I haven't decided on just yet.

It'd still mean I have part of my site running WAMP and part of it running IIS/Sql Server though, so it's still two isolated platforms running on one machine...

Comment: You should ask yourself how much would it take to build e-commerce yourself and what would you rather spend time doing, developing core features or introducing new business features specific for your company. If 7k is too much, then you probably need to think about the type of business you are building. All that said, we created a new e-commerce product based on MVC4 with available source code that you can check out at [virtocommerce.com](http://virtocommerce.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, [Google Checkout](http://checkout.google.com/seller/integrate_custom.html) and [Checkout by Amazon](http://checkout.google.com/seller/integrate_custom.html) should work for me. Interestingly, they're practically identical services.